# Declare a function signature with decltype()

Tags: c++, c++11, definition, decltype

Is it possible to declare a function `bar` to have the same signature as function `foo`?

```
int foo(int a)
{
    return 0; 
}

decltype(foo) bar
{
    return 1;
} //imaginary syntax
```

Comment: Side-remark: It's not allowed to use typedefs/aliases like `using foo_t = int(int);` to *define* a function, declaring is ok.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible for definitions. And if it was: how would you specify the names of the parameters?

Comment: @Agentlien I don't know, so here I ask

Comment: @Agentlien There are cases where you simply don't *need* the argument names.

Comment: @DanielFrey That's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the same applies as for typedefs and aliases: You may use `decltype` to *declare* a function, but not to define it:

```
int foo();

decltype(foo) bar;

int foo()
{
    return bar();
}

int bar() { return 0; }
```

is accepted by clang++3.5 and g++4.8.1

---

[dcl.fct.def.general]/2 forbids (grammatically) the definition of a function w/o parentheses:

> The declarator in a function-definition shall have the form
>
> `D1 (` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>   ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub> exception-specification<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> trailing-return-type<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> as described in 8.3.5.

Comment: Also see [dcl.fct]/10

Comment: I thought he was talking about duplicating the function parameters of `foo` in `bar`...

Comment: @0x499602D2 I didn't accept this answer ;) Well you can use `decltype` to replicate the signature including function parameters of `foo` in `bar`, but only for the declaration. If you want to define a `bar` that the same signature as `foo`, you'll need to use templates. SoapBox shows a simple version of that; it could also be done as a static member function of a class template, with a perfect replication of the signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variadic templates to define a function which has the same signature as *any* function:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(char const *blah) { return 0; }

template<typename... Args>
auto bar(Args ... args) -> decltype(foo(args...))
{
    return 1; 
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo("test") << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar("test") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This could also be modified slightly to pass "foo" as the first template argument, so that you could use the same "bar" with many different "foo"s:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto bar(Func f, Args ... args) -> decltype(f(args...))
{
    return 1; 
}

int baz(double d) { return 3; }

int main() {
    std::cout << bar(&foo, "test") << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar(&baz, 1.2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has a similar signature, but not the same ;) E.g. it also (greedily) accepts implicit conversions for its arguments, producing different instantiations.

Comment: @dyp true but probably the closest possible to what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Ah I misread the OP. I thought the question was "is it possible to use *decltype* to declare...".

Comment: Also note that this cannot reproduce reference parameters. If you used perfect forwarding, it wouldn't reproduce by-value parameters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not trivially as you're posing, since you cannot set the arguments directly. decltype(foo) does return the actual type of foo, so you can use that to instantiate a template traits class that then exposes the return type and arguments type (somehow), and then use that to define your function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sf(int, float, double, bool) {}
template <typename RV, typename... args>
RV func(args... as) {
  printf("%d %f %f %d\n", as...);
  return sf(as...);
}
template <typename RV, typename... args>
RV(*generateFunc(RV(*)(args...)))(args...) {
  return &func<RV, args...>;
}

int main() {
  decltype(sf) *f = generateFunc(sf);
  f(42, 1.0f, 12.0, true);
}
```

This generates a function to match sf's signature and then forwards the call to it.

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Comment: @Paranaix I was trying out the code in a compiler before posting it. Sorry about double-checking.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes into mind is that you need to name the parameters so no, you can't.

The type of foo is:

```
int(int)
```

so any imaginary declaration syntax like:

```
decltype(foo) bar { //imaginary syntax
  // can't access parameter
  return 1;
}
```

will have the problem that `bar` can't access parameters.

So the best you can do is what @dyp suggests.

One other thing you could do is to check if two functions have the same signature:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo), decltype(bar)>::value, "Invalid bar signature");
```