# How to define a function with decltype and access parameters

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to hook the Windows API, but once more hook APIs are needed, defining functions will become a big problem.Like this:

```
decltype(MessageBoxA)* Old_MessageBoxA = MessageBoxA;

int WINAPI New_MessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    return Old_MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hooked MessageBoxA", "Hooked MessageBoxA", NULL);
}

//
// It takes a lot of work to define functions
//

BOOL
InstallHook(
        void
)
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach((PVOID*)&Old_MessageBoxA, New_MessageBoxA);
    auto ret = DetourTransactionCommit();
}
```

I want to make my job easier,the question now is how to use decltype to automatically define functions.And I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055039/declare-a-function-signature-with-decltype),but the solution in this link didn't help me,I hope to improve my code like:

```
decltype(MessageBoxA)* Old_MessageBoxA = MessageBoxA;

decltype(MessageBoxA) New_MessageBoxA
{
    // And I can access parameters
    return Old_MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hooked MessageBoxA", "Hooked MessageBoxA", NULL);
}

BOOL
InstallHook(
        void
)
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach((PVOID*)&Old_MessageBoxA, New_MessageBoxA);
    auto ret = DetourTransactionCommit();
}
```

I know this problem can be solved through templates,but I am not good at templates.Please help.

Comment: What you are attempting to do is generally not possible in C++. You can't define a function definition in terms of another function type like you are trying to do. The code in the other question is using templates to act as proxies between functions, which is doable, but that is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Any method can make this easier, whether it is decltype or template,I could edit the question later.